# Qiskit: Measure circuit until specific bitstring sampled

Tags: qiskit, measurement

I'm implementing a quantum algorithm that involves measuring a circuit until a bitstring with a particular property is sampled. I want both the bitstring and the number of measurements it took until the bitstring was sampled.

In order to avoid re-transpiling the circuit each time, I've done the following:

```
qc = ...
count = 0
aer_sim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
t_qc = transpile(qc, aer_sim)
qobj = assemble(t_qc, shots=1)
bs = ""
while not cond(bs)
    count += 1
    result = aer_sim.run(qobj, memory=True).result()
    bs = result.get_memory()

return bs, cond
```

Is there a better way of doing this? E.g. some sort of conditional measurement or call back method? Thanks